# How to get the time zone from a datetime string

Tags: java, android, timezone, datetime-format, string-parsing

How can I get the time zone from a datetime string with this format `2013-08-15T13:00:00-07:00`?

Comment: Which format do you want? The offset? The display name? The three-letter code?

Answer (score 1):

You could take the time offset from Andreas answer and use below sinppet to get TimeZone object.

```
TimeZone tmzo = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"+offset);
System.out.println(tmzo.getID());
```

Answer (score 1):

if Java 8, you can parse directly with [ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) format

```
String input = "2013-08-15T13:00:00-07:00";                             
ZonedDateTime zDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);            
ZoneId zone = zDateTime.getZone();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7 you can parse with and without TZ and than calculate the offset, taking your current TZ offset into account.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
Date withTZ = sdf.parse("2013-08-15T13:00:00-07:00");

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date noTZ = sdf2.parse("2013-08-15T13:00:00-07:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. The following assumes [XML dateTime](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) syntax:

```
String input = "2013-08-15T13:00:00-07:00";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:[+-]\\d{2}:\\d{2}|Z)$").matcher(input);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println("Time zone: " + m.group());
else
    System.out.println("No time zone found");
```

Answer (score -2):

> 2013-08-15T13:00:00-07:00

the last `-7:00 means GMT-7`
That is MST (Mountain Standard Time)

That timezone is using in US and Canada

Comment: What part of that answer describes how to get the time zone programmatically in Java?